# Cordova plugin on iOS is not calling native code

Tags: ios, cordova-plugins

I am trying to call a plugin on pagehide event (from javascript)- but the call of the native function seems not to work.
My calling javascript:

```
window.addEventListener("pagehide", function() {

               Hello.abc(function() {
                   console.log("sucess");
               }, function() {
                   console.log('error');
               }, ['Sample'])
           });
```

In my plugins-directory:

Hello.h:

```
 #import <Cordova/CDV.h>

@interface Hello : CDVPlugin

- (void)hello:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *) command;

@end
```

Hello.m

```
    #import "Hello.h"
    #import <Cordova/CDV.h>
    @interface Hello ()
    {
        NSString *strCallBackID;
    }


    @end

    @implementation Hello



    - (void)hello:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *) command{
    strCallBackID=command.callbackId;
    NSString *result=@"Hello";
    NSLog(@"Hello");
    CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString: result]; 
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:strCallBackID];
    }
@end
```

My plugin code:

```
cordova.define("ubee-plugin-hello.Hello", function(require, exports, module) {
module.exports = Hello = {

               abc : function(successCallback, errorCallback, params) {
               console.log("PARAM->"+params);

               var exec = require('cordova/exec');
               exec(successCallback, errorCallback, 'Hello', 'hello', [params]);
               }
};
});
```

Comment: Can you post also the plugin code? I don't see any binding from the js code to the native code here

Comment: Do you get your params printed out in the log?

Comment: Yes I want to get params printed out in the log.

Comment: try to replace `var exec = require('cordova/exec'); exec(...)` with `cordova.exec(...)` as the current [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/#the-javascript-interface) suggests.

Comment: I did but not working. I see that 'resetting plugins due to page load' log in xcode console.

Comment: But do you see the `console.log("PARAM->"+params);`?

Comment: No i can not see any log. As the context of window is changed.